# &mut self borrow lives after return

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm working on a piece of code that has some structs which contain references to each other, and I've run into an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

```rust
// demonstration of what the problem is

struct State<T>(T);
struct Query<'a, T>(&'a T);

impl<T> State<T> {
    fn query(&mut self) -> Option<Query<'_, T>> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

struct Container<T>(Vec<State<T>>);

impl<T> Container<T> {
    fn query(&mut self) -> Option<Query<'_, T>> {
        let query = self.0.last_mut()?.query();

        if let Some(query) = query {
            return Some(query);
        }

        // i feel like i should be able to use &mut self again here but i can't :(

        self.0.pop(); 
        // error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
        return self.query();
        // error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
    }
}
```

Why, in this example, can I not borrow again after the if block? Why does the lifetime of the borrow continue on after returning?

Comment: The workaround in your case is difficult. I got it to compile with unsafe, but I'm not sure if this is sound https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=87ea8b6a4e2150a602bababfbb7c4332

Comment: Here's an iterative one so you don't accidentally blow the stack https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f3e9605af972f84d3dea0bcbe804631e

Comment: @drewtato It is sound.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known limitation of the current borrow checker](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/latest/polonius_the_crab/#rationale-limitations-of-the-nll-borrow-checker). It will be fixed with the introduction of the new polonius borrow checker.

Currently, there are two ways to work around it:

- use `unsafe`
- reword the code so that the borrow checker understands it

The `unsafe` route can usually be abstracted by using the [`polonius_the_crab`](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab) crate, to make sure your problem actually fits this usecase, and to keep Rusts compile time safety guarantees.

In your case, this is how this would look like using `polonius_the_crab`:

```rust
use polonius_the_crab::prelude::*;

struct State<T>(T);
struct Query<'a, T>(&'a T);

impl<T> State<T> {
    fn query(&mut self) -> Option<Query<'_, T>> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

struct Container<T>(Vec<State<T>>);

impl<T> Container<T> {
    fn query(&mut self) -> Option<Query<'_, T>> {
        let mut this = self;

        polonius!(|this| -> Option<Query<'polonius, T>> {
            match this.0.last_mut() {
                None => polonius_return!(None),
                Some(state) => {
                    if let Some(query) = state.query() {
                        polonius_return!(Some(query));
                    }
                }
            };
        });

        this.0.pop();
        return this.query();
    }
}
```

The reason why we need to `let mut this = self;` is because internally, the `polonius!` macro takes ownership of `this`, uses it, and then at the end write `this` back to the variable. And `&mut self` cannot be written into. There sadly is no way to write `&mut self` as `mut self: &mut Self`, so we need to store it in a temporal variable I chose to name `this`.

Essentially, where you write:

> i feel like i should be able to use &mut self again here but i can't

This is exactly what this crate fixes.

A more in-depth explanation of this problem and its possible other solutions can be found in the [`polonius_the_crab` documentation](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/latest/polonius_the_crab/#explanation).

Answer (score 0):

With the unsightly fact that `query()` is called twice, this solution is possible:

```
impl<T> Container<T> {
    fn query(&mut self) -> Option<Query<'_, T>> {
        if self.0.is_empty() { return None; }
        if self.0.last_mut().unwrap().query().is_some() {
            self.0.last_mut().unwrap().query()
        } else {
            self.0.pop();
            self.query()
        }
    }
}
```